# How to show (open in) view controller to export content in iOS 7

Tags: xcode, ios7

I was trying to create a photo editor app. every thing is good but i have no idea about the API for bringing the (open in) view to export the photo into another application or share it through airdrop. How can I achieve this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/) and [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/)